# Cannot install OJS on freebsd php 7.2

Tags: php, apache, freebsd, ojs

I'm trying install to my vmware freebsd, i did install msqli, php, apache all lastest version and when i tried to install ojs im gettings this errors, please help thanks.

```
Function create_function() is deprecated in in /usr/local/www/apache24/data/ojs-3.1.0-1/lib/pkp/classes/install/form/InstallForm.inc.php on line 92

Deprecated: Non-static method Application::getName() should not be called statically in /usr/local/www/apache24/data/ojs-3.1.0-1/lib/pkp/classes/install/form/InstallForm.inc.php on line 146

Deprecated: Non-static method Application::getName() should not be called statically in /usr/local/www/apache24/data/ojs-3.1.0-1/lib/pkp/classes/install/form/InstallForm.inc.php on line 148

Deprecated: Non-static method Application::getName() should not be called statically in /usr/local/www/apache24/data/ojs-3.1.0-1/lib/pkp/classes/install/form/InstallForm.inc.php on line 150

Deprecated: Non-static method VersionCheck::getCurrentCodeVersion() should not be called statically in /usr/local/www/apache24/data/ojs-3.1.0-1/lib/pkp/classes/install/form/MaintenanceForm.inc.php on line 37

Deprecated: Non-static method PKPRequest::getUserVar() should not be called statically in /usr/local/www/apache24/data/ojs-3.1.0-1/lib/pkp/classes/form/Form.inc.php on line 369

Deprecated: Non-static method PKPRequest::_checkThis() should not be called statically in /usr/local/www/apache24/data/ojs-3.1.0-1/lib/pkp/classes/core/PKPRequest.inc.php on line 592

Deprecated: Function create_function() is deprecated in /usr/local/www/apache24/data/ojs-3.1.0-1/lib/pkp/lib/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/Smarty_Compiler.class.php on line 269

Deprecated: The each() function is deprecated. This message will be suppressed on further calls in /usr/local/www/apache24/data/ojs-3.1.0-1/lib/pkp/lib/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/Smarty_Compiler.class.php on line 559

Deprecated: Function create_function() is deprecated in /usr/local/www/apache24/data/ojs-3.1.0-1/lib/pkp/lib/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/Smarty_Compiler.class.php on line 269

Deprecated: Function create_function() is deprecated in /usr/local/www/apache24/data/ojs-3.1.0-1/lib/pkp/lib/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/Smarty_Compiler.class.php on line 269

Deprecated: Function create_function() is deprecated in /usr/local/www/apache24/data/ojs-3.1.0-1/lib/pkp/lib/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/Smarty_Compiler.class.php on line 269
```

Comment: I've never heard of OJS, but it looks like it relies on features that are deprecated in PHP 7.2 (and some in 5.6, judging by the errors). There might be a more up-to-date version you can use. If not then you can disable the deprecation notices, although you'll eventually run into further problems if you upgrade PHP to a version that removes these features entirely.

Answer (score 0):

OJS currently (as of OJS 3.1.0-1) relies on the `create_function` function, but that dependency is not major and will be removed before the function is no longer available in PHP.

I recommend disabling deprecation warnings and keeping your OJS up to date.

Comment: Thanks for help, ill disable the warnings.

Answer (score 0):

OK, i installed ojs but after the installation im getting the blank page when im opening the logs, im getting this error;

```
 Recoverable fatal error: ini_set(): Cannot set 'user' save handler by ini_set() or session_module_name() in /usr/local/www/apache24/data/lib/pkp/classes/session/SessionManager.inc.php on line 36
```

Any recommend would be nice for me guys.

Comment: OK, i solved the problem, pkp classes have php 7.2 incompabilities, i patch them.